# WooCommerce проблема с фильтром по атрибутам

Tags: woocommerce, filter

Есть проблема что если после выбора фильтра товаров больше чем может быть отображено на 1 странице, не могу перейти на 2 страницу, очень долго грузит и потом вылетает "сайте выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз", пробывал разные плагины для фильтров товаров, одно и то же. Как я понимаю проблема с линковкой, но как ее решить, может кто знает?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ на вопрос, во первых нужно проверить как называется ваша категория для линковки (Слаг), должно быть все латинскими буквами, во вторых [вот ссылка](http://www.sdelaysite.com/seo-verstka-wordpress/reshenie-problemy-category-wp) на статью если вам не помог вариант со сменой слага с кириллицы на латиницу.